# Laravel - destroy then update deleted_by

Tags: laravel

I'm having an error when after using `destroy` I need to update my `deleted_by` field. I heard about revisionable but I'm trying to stay as simple as possible with my application. Is it even possible to throw another function inside a `destroy`?

```
public function destroy($id, Department $department)
  {
        if(Department::destroy($id)) {
            $department->update([
                'deleted_by' => Auth::user()->id,
            ]);
        }
  }
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use route model binding and do it like this:

```php
public function destroy(Department $department)
{
    if($department->delete()) {
        $department->update([
            'deleted_by' => Auth::user()->id,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing wrong type hinting.

```
public function destroy(Department $department)
  {
        if($department->delete()) {
            $department->update([
                'deleted_by' => Auth::user()->id,
            ]);
        }
  }
```